# How to fix "The type or namespace name 'UI' does not exist in the namespace after implementing Unit test cases in Unity using TestRunner

Tags: c#, unit-testing, unity-game-engine, windows-mixed-reality

Hi I am trying to implement Unit test cases in Unity for my project using testrunner. I have created the test folder for edit mode. In the test folder there is the assembly definition file.In the assembly definition file you have to give reference to where the scripts are created.

In the scripts folder I have created the assembly definition file by right-clicking in the scripts folder->Create->Assembly definition.But the moment I create this file,problems start arising like :

```
Assets\Scripts\ExplodeViewLabels.cs(4,7): error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'TMPro' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Assets\Scripts\LandingGear.cs(5,7): error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'TMPro' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Assets\Scripts\SceneController.cs(3,17): error CS0234: The type or namespace name 'MixedReality' does not exist in the namespace 'Microsoft' (are you missing an assembly reference?)
```

and much more the screenshot I am attaching [here](https://prnt.sc/BRu08bktKkV8)

I tried overcoming the error by giving reference to the [assembly definition file in the scripts as Unity.TextMeshPro](https://prnt.sc/aw2y2Yx4Ap6J) and then click apply. The error for textMeshPro was done but other errors still  persists like

```
Assets\Scripts\SceneController.cs(3,17): error CS0234: The type or namespace name 'MixedReality' does not exist in the namespace 'Microsoft' (are you missing an assembly reference?)
```

and much more. I tried to give whatever reference I had with Microsoft.MixedReality, like the ones I have indicated in this [screenshot](https://prnt.sc/cRGSkV8Kh7bt). I addded all the three which I have indicated in the red box in the screenshot but there is no use.

Comment: For all of those errors, you need to figure out where the code is stored, which assemblies they are in and then add the assembly to the ScriptRef.

Answer (score 0):

Go to your SceneController.cs script and see which using statements you have. I think probably you're missing assembly definitions to the actual package(s) you're using in the script. Assembly definitions are kind of a pain to use and it's not enough to have SOME of the files included.

Comment: thanks for the answer. I did go into the SceneController.cs script. The statement where the red squiggly lines were coming were for using Microsoft.MixedReality.Toolkit.UI; I tried to look into the packages section of under the Project folder but I could find toolkit files , but couldnt find .UI file for any of the toolkit packages.You can see the project structure here : https://prnt.sc/hy_PHZXRx0KF indicated in the red box .I tried to find the appropriate assembly defintion file which was suggested when you click on the big dot like thing under the assembly definition in inspector too

Comment: @ChethanV - Have you tried expanding all of those folders and looking through the files to see where exactly the functions are that you're trying to use?

Comment: yeah I did expand all the files and looked for .UI stuff, but didnt find it anywhere